# DCMTK dcm2json produces invalid JSON for broken DS or IS values

Tags: javascript, node.js, dicom, dcmtk

DCMTK dcm2json produces invalid JSON for broken DS or IS values see https://support.dcmtk.org/redmine/issues/769

The JSON will contain values like this example:

```
"00291003": {"vr":"IS","Value":[F]},
```

Where 'F' is clearly not a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be worked around in a Nodejs environment by first running the raw unparsed JSON through the following.

```
const jsonRepair = (rawJson) => {
    let regex1 =  /\[([^"]+)\]/g
    let isNumRegex = /^[-.0-9]*\d$/g
    let matches = undefined
    while ((matches = regex1.exec(rawJson)) !== null) {
        if (!isNumRegex.test(matches[1])) {
            rawJson = rawJson.replace(matches[0], `["${matches[1]}"]`)
            console.log(matches[0], `[${matches[1]}]`)
        }
    }
    return rawJson
}
```